# Função que funciona em edit/django, mas não funciona na wiki/django. Por que?

Tags: html, python, django

Eu estou tentando fazer uma funçãoo para editar wikis.

Quando eu entro em edit/django ela me retorna tudo certo, mas quando entro na wiki/django, por exemplo, onde tem o botão para editar, ela retorna este erro:

> NoReverseMatch at /wiki/Django Reverse for 'edit_page' with arguments
> '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit/(?P<page_title>[^/]+)$']

views.py:

```
def edit_page(request, page_title):
    content = util.get_entry(page_title)
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/edit.html", {
        "page_title": page_title,
        "content": content
    })
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from . import views
app_name = "encyclopedia"

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("wiki/<str:page>", views.wiki_page, name="wiki_page"),
    path("create", views.add_entry, name="add_entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search"),
     path("edit/<str:page_title>", views.edit_page, name="edit_page")
]
```

wiki.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit_page' page_title %}">edit</a>
    {{ entry_content|safe }}

{% endblock %}
```

edit.html:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ page_title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <form action="{% url 'encyclopedia:edit_page' page_title %}" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %} 
        <h1>Edit Page</h1>
        <textarea name="edit-content" id="textarea-content">{{ content }}</textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save-edit" type="submit">save changes</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Você definiu a função `views.wiki_page`? Ela está sendo referenciada na configuração da url, mas eu não vi ela em seu `views.py`.